# Giant TCR SLR2 2015 vs Giant Defy Composite 2 2013

Tags: road-bike

this is the first time i gonna buy and ride a road bike. Mainly use to commute everyday and exercise. I'm tall 5"3 and i'm looking for a bike which is durable,fast, better to upgrade later. And i got 2 options.

1. Giant Defy Composite 2 2013 Size Small ( 46.5cm ) i think. I got a deal on Ebay, it still new and i got price 1150 + 150 for shipping. So $1300 total. ( SRAM Apex gear,full carbon frame )
2. Giant TCR SLR2 2015 from a local bike shop. Original price $1500 and they discount for me so i only pay $1200 for a new one and i can choose the size...may be Extra Small. ( 105 gear, premium alluminum,carbon fork)

Today i went to the store and try the Aluminum Defy 5, and it's ok. I try the other bike Cannondale CAAD10 but I got more harder to control, may be the handbar more lower and different geometry. I didn't have chance to try the TCR because they didn't have XS or S size.

So now i have to choose one of it. Both of them must be fast, accept the counter price on ebay before it gone, or order TCR before Black Friday to have a good discount.
I also wonder does it hard to maintain Defy composite than TCR, the street in my place a lot of pump and sometime have to ride on pavel.

Looking for advise of you guys. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to [Bicycles.SE] @Mike. I think this question is likely to be closed because it's a shopping question and answers will not help anyone else in the future.

Comment: Oh sorry, i don't know that. So please closed it. I can't delete it cause it got answered and....need moderator something.

Answer (score 2):

As a general answer to this kind of question, I recommend that you buy from your local bike shop. While shops can vary, if they seem to provide reasonable service and the price is reasonable, it's worth buying from them for several reasons

- the profit on your sale will help them stay in business - so they will be there when you need service.
- many shops bundle clothing, shoes, helmet, bottles, lights, and such with the sale - so you end up with a better deal.
- many shops will give you a free service and free adjustments - if you bought from them.

Since there *will* come a time when you need them, start the relationship now.